# React syntax explanation for setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

what is the difference between the following in React?

```
this.setState({[name]: value })
```

and

```
this.setState({name: value });
```

Comment: One sets `this.state.name` to `value`, the other sets `this.state[name]` to `value`.

Comment: Yes but what is the difference. Because when I'm writing only name without bracket I having errors

Comment: That *is* the difference. If you still have a specific problem after reading the duplicate please [edit] to give a [mcve], not just *"having errors"*.